# error Error: could not handle the request

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

```html
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'

admin.initializeApp()

export const helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    response.send("")
})

export const clientRequest = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

    //if (["POST", "OPTIONS"].indexOf(request.method.toUpperCase()) === -1) response.send('wrong request type')

    const store = admin.firestore()

    const sendData = {
        clientName: 'qwe!'
    };

    store
        .collection('items')
        .add(sendData)
        .then(success => {
            response.send("");
        }).catch(error => {
            response.send(error)
        })
})
```

Why? Yesterday that work!

i  functions: packaged functions (46.51 KB) for uploading
+  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
i  functions: updating function helloWorld...
i  functions: updating function clientRequest...
+  functions[clientRequest]: Successful update operation.
+  functions[helloWorld]: Successful update operation.
+  Deploy complete!

Comment: What happens if you try to re-deploy?

Comment: Anything special in the Functions log on the Firebase console?

Comment: Function execution took 60002 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'
and.. only name function and triangle red warning

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you change the end of your code to

```
    .then(success => {
        response.status(200).send("");
    }).catch(error => {
        response.status(500).send(error)
    })
```

Comment: tu for answer, I thought firebase detect errors at one's own level. I use it now.